# Flutter lags when opening the keyboard

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-ui

I have a flutter project (chat) with a flutter/material.dart vaporizer. When opening the keyboard (`TextField`), lags appear. I don't quite understand the reason. Can you help?

[Video](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOiofFFfZ8LaruT3M7xWNe4GLfvP2E9FlxwnGKeXh4-mIsWGaPH0r7HEhzLlmI2Lw/photo/AF1QipNelFpXNWjrMaaS-f_vqe3qJAkr-TsFYsT6mio5?key=VS1lZHRLendnRnRLcW1SQ0JzdHVhRVhzenl2aUh3)

[image]

I added `Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`, but it didn't help.
I don't understand why even after adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,` a lot of frames appear there when opening the keyboard

The shortest possible code. Link to the full below

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final observer = Provider.of<Observer>(context, listen: true);
    var _keyboardVisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;

    return PickupLayout(
      scaffold: Fiberchat.getNTPWrappedWidget(WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: isgeneratingSomethingLoader == true
              ? () async {
                  return Future.value(false);
                }
              : isemojiShowing == true
                  ? () {
                      setState(() {
                        isemojiShowing = false;
                        keyboardFocusNode.unfocus();
                      });
                      return Future.value(false);
                    }
                  : () async {
                      setLastSeen();
                      WidgetsBinding.instance!
                          .addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
                        var currentpeer = Provider.of<CurrentChatPeer>(
                            this.context,
                            listen: false);
                        currentpeer.setpeer(newpeerid: '');
                        if (lastSeen == peerNo)
                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection(DbPaths.collectionusers)
                              .doc(currentUserNo)
                              .update(
                            {Dbkeys.lastSeen: true},
                          );
                      });

                      return Future.value(true);
                    },
          child: ScopedModel<DataModel>(
              model: _cachedModel,
              child: ScopedModelDescendant<DataModel>(
                  builder: (context, child, _model) {
                _cachedModel = _model;
                updateLocalUserData(_model);
                return peer != null
                    ? Stack(
                        children: [
                          Scaffold(
                              key: _scaffold,
                              appBar: AppBar(
                                elevation: DESIGN_TYPE == Themetype.messenger
                                    ? 0.4
                                    : 1,
                                titleSpacing: -14,
                                leading: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                                  width: 10,
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                                      size: 20,
                                      color: DESIGN_TYPE == Themetype.whatsapp
                                          ? fiberchatWhite
                                          : fiberchatBlack,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (isDeletedDoc == true) {
                                        Navigator.of(context)
                                            .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                FiberchatWrapper(),
                                          ),
                                          (Route route) => false,
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ...
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              body: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Container(
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                      color: DESIGN_TYPE == Themetype.whatsapp
                                          ? fiberchatChatbackground
                                          : fiberchatWhite,
                                      image: new DecorationImage(
                                          image: peer![Dbkeys.wallpaper] == null
                                              ? AssetImage(
                                                  "assets/images/background.png")
                                              : Image.file(File(
                                                      peer![Dbkeys.wallpaper]))
                                                  .image,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                    Scaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    appBar: AppBar(),
                    body: PageView(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      isDeletedDoc == true
                                          ? Center(
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                        15, 60, 15, 15),
                                                child: Text(
                                                    getTranslated(this.context,
                                                        'chatdeleted'),
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: fiberchatGrey)),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          : Column(
                                              children: [
                                                // List of messages

                                                buildMessages(context),
                                                // Input content
                                                isBlocked()
                                                    ? AlertDialog(
                                                        ...
                                                        ],
                                                      )
                                                    : hasPeerBlockedMe == true
                                                        ? Container(
                                                            
                                                            ...
                                                        : buildInputAndroid(
                                                            context,
                                                            isemojiShowing,
                                                            refreshInput,
                                                            _keyboardVisible)
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                                  buildLoading()
                                ],
                              )),
                          buildLoadingThumbnail(),
                        ],
                      )
                    : Container();
              })))),
    );
  }
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/4qvGRmyL

Comment: Have you tried running the release build on a real device?

Comment: @voidvoid Video from a real device. Tested on two real devices (redmi note 9s & poco x3 pro). Everywhere lags

Comment: You still didn't answer if it's the release build. Also from the video it's clear that the screen is resizing due to the keyboard appearing, so the build methods that depend on the screen size with a `MediaQuery` will be rebuilt when the keyboard is appearing, many times during the showing of the keyboard. Also, your code is incomplete, are you perhaps keeping all of the message widgets alive and not using any kind of pagination?

Comment: @voidvoid Trying different compilation modes now, I noticed that there are no lags in the `--profile` mode. Weird

Comment: The `--profile` build is similar in performance to `--release`. It's not strange for debug builds to be significantly slower than release builds, so that's not weird. See https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes for more details.

Comment: @voidvoid Thanks, I just started learning. It is strange that this information could not be found on the Internet ..